# Transformar a primeira letra de todas as palavras de uma string em maiúscula com PHP

Tags: php

Baseado na função [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ucfirst.php), porém ao invés de converter somente a primeira letra da primeira palavra, como fazer, utilizando PHP, para que a primeira letra de todas as palavras de uma string sejam convertidas para maiúsculo?

Dessa forma, seguindo o padrão de *"nome completo"*, exemplo:

```
'joão silva' => 'João Silva'
'maria Silva' => 'Maria Silva'
'gustavo da silva' => 'Gustavo Da Silva'
'GUILHERME DE CAMPOS' => 'Guilherme De Campos'
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ucwords.php) para este fim:

> Converte para maiúsculas o primeiro caractere de cada palavra

O problema de usar `ucwords` seria quando os caracteres iniciais forem acentuados, no caso não seriam convertidos em maiúsculos. Recomendo o uso de `mb_convert_case`, mas caso tenha certeza de que nenhum nome inicie com acento, então `ucwords` dá conta do recado.

```
// exemplo 1
$str = 'joão silva';
echo ucwords( $str );

// exemplo 2
$str = 'joão silva';
echo mb_convert_case( $str , MB_CASE_TITLE , 'UTF-8' );
```

O output de ambos é `João Silva`, como pode ver o exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/HKDO3v).